# Hibernate Second level cache doesn't work

Tags: java, hibernate, second-level-cache

i'm stuck a bit and can't understand what's wrong with my configuration of second level cache.
pom file

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.36</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
 <property name="format_sql">true</property>
 <property name="use_sql_comments">true</property>
 <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
 <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
 <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">100</property>
 <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</property>
 <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
 <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>   
 <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory</property>
 <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
 <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
 <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_configuration_file_resource_path">ehcache.xml</property>
```

ehcache.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache>

 <defaultCache maxElementsInMemory="100" eternal="false" timeToIdleSeconds="120" timeToLiveSeconds="200" />    

<cache
    name="version2Cache"
    maxElementsInMemory="100000"
    eternal="true"
    overflowToDisk="false"
    memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU"
    statistics="true"
/>
</ehcache>
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "version")
@Cacheable
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE,region="version2Cache")
public class VersionData implements Serializable
{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7355281418627668744L;

    @Id 
    @Column(name="VERSION_ID")  
    private String versionId;



    /**
     * user docname
     */
    @Column(name = "DOC_NAME")
    private String docName; 


    /**
     * user versionModivied
     */
    @Column(name = "VERSION_MODIFIED")
    @Type(type = "timestamp")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Date versionModivied;
    /**
     * user zvitId
     */
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="ZVIT_ID")
    private ZvitData zvitId;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity=TermData.class, mappedBy = "versionId", cascade=javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<TermData> terms;
//getters, setters, hashcode, equals
}
```

And I run unit test

```
@Test
    public void testCache() throws ReportException
    {
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = ReportsFactory.getSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        VersionData versionData = (VersionData) session.load(VersionData.class, "1");
        System.out.println(versionData.getDocName());
        session.close();

        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        versionData = (VersionData) session.load(VersionData.class, "1");
        System.out.println(versionData.getDocName());
        session.close();
    }
```

And I see in console that there are actually two queries running in database, but with working second level cache there should be one.

EDDITED:
Thank you Madhusudana Reddy Sunnapu. My mistake was that I didn't read console message properly :( 
I didn't cached embedded objects. And It looked like query was working twice. But second time it didn't really loaded VersionData, but queried embedded objects. And I missed it. Sorry for troubling. It's really stupid mistake of mine:(

Comment: have you used <cache usage="read-only" /> on your `.hbm.xml` File.???

Comment: @Evgen I don't see any issues with the configuration. Can you show the console output where you are seeing two queries?

Comment: I stated cache usage in my entity @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE,region="version2Cache"). I don't have any other place where i set it

Comment: @Evgen Glad that helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

You Should add this Content and retry your Test. Probably you get your answer.

```
<ehcache>
     ....
     ....
     //your Code
     .....
     .....
    <cache name="package.Name.VersionData"   
        maxElementsInMemory="100"   
        eternal="false"   
        timeToIdleSeconds="5"   
        timeToLiveSeconds="200" />  
    </ehcache>
```